# Grep page source for URL

Tags: terminal, grep

I have a webpage source in a text doc, there's a few lines like so:

```
"rid" : 'http://web.site/urlhere',
```

How do I use Linux/terminal to grep just the `http://web.site/urlhere` portion?

Comment: Are you searching for a specific url (as your example indicates)... or generic urls that occur in single quotes after a colon...  or something else?  Being specific helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the *-o* option to grep to tell it to only display the matching pattern.

```
grep -o http://web.site/urlhere somefile.txt
```

Assuming you're looking for generic URLs, you could start with something like this (and probably improve it):

```
grep -o "'http.*'" someFile.txt | sed "s/'//g"
```

This will search for the text *http* after a single quote and will include all the characters from that line until the last single quote.  It will then pipe the result (only the matching pattern) to sed and remove the single quotes.

Note: You could run into trouble if you have more single quotes after the url (but your question doesn't mention that)...

Since you're question is very non-specific, there are probably many other input conditions that could cause problems, but the above should be a good starting point.

More info on grep:    http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep